# C How can I calculate an average of a list without loops?

Tags: c, list, average

So I created a linked List in C using structs and it stores ints. My mission is to calculate the average of the values in the list without using recursion or loops.
I already have the list's item count I just need the sum.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the list length bounded? For unbounded lists you will need some kind of loop or recursion. A workaround (cheating?) would be to calculate the average or the sum already during list construction.

Comment: Add values to sum when you are adding elements to the list?

Comment: what are "loops"?  Only `for (...)`, or `while (...)` too and `goto`?

Comment: I already found the solution and wrote it here, but thank you for your help! :) and yea, goto is forbidden.

Answer (score 4):

Simply have two varibles - count, total; Update them in Add and Delete.
When u want avg, just return total/count.

Comment: Wow I actually just thought of it xD thank you anyway!

Answer (score -1):

The list is not length bounded, but i found a solution.
I create a variable in the list's ateuct to save the sum of the list, and i change the sum of the list each time I add or remove a cell. When I want to calculate the sums I'll just divide the sum by the count.

Thank you anyway for your help :)

Comment: And you filled the list without a loop or recursion?

Comment: @Peter G. Yea, no need for loops or recursion, because this js a linked list where each cell has pointers of the previos and next cell, and a pointer to the list who owns the cell.

Comment: Answer good in theory for languages in general, but scant on C details.  Posting the C implementation would allow folks to assess its quality/weaknesses.